# How do you correct errors in Google Patents?

Tags: google-patents

In reference to the patent: [US163625](https://www.google.com/patents/US163625)

The Inventor's name should be "Ariette Baird." How does this happen, and is there any way to correct copy errors in patents?

Answer (score 3):

Google OCR sometimes have problems, You are right actual patent has same spelling. Any ways 'Ask Patent' is not direct link to Google. you can use '**Send Feedback**' of Google patents to report this error.

[image]

However To correct inventor name in patent, you can see MPEP 602.01(c)(2)   Correcting or Updating Inventor Name 37 CFR 1.48(f) – Request Filed On or After September 16, 2012 [R-11.2013]

> (f) Correcting or updating the name of an inventor: Any request to
> **correct or update the name of the inventor** or a joint inventor, or the
> order of the names of joint inventors, in a nonprovisional application
> must include: (1) An application data sheet in accordance with §1.76
> that identifies each inventor by his or her legal name in the desired
> order; and (2) The processing fee set forth in §1.17(i).
>
> > ................. and allows an applicant to adjust the order of the names of joint inventors (e.g., to control the order of names on a printed patent). 37 CFR 1.48(f) specifically provides that any request to correct or update the name of the inventor or a joint inventor, or the order of the names of joint inventors, in a nonprovisional application must include: (1) an application data sheet in accordance with 37 CFR 1.76 that identifies each inventor by his or her legal name in the desired order; and (2) the processing fee set forth in 37 CFR 1.17(i). The request should also identify the desired inventor name change.

for more information please visit [MPEP](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s602.html)

Comment: The inventor name shown on the scanned PDF at the USPTO is ARIETTE BAIRD.