# How to change the order of inventors after a patent is granted?

Tags: uspto, inventorship

Is it possible to change the listed order of inventors **after** a utility patent application is granted by USPTO? And if so, how could I go about doing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you correct errors in Google Patents?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/12392/how-do-you-correct-errors-in-google-patents)

Comment: @Pushpak I had read that thread. It talks about correcting inventor details **before** the patent application is granted.

Comment: Order is alphabetical by default, or to order provided in form, you can contact your agent.

Comment: Ok. I'm being told that order of inventors cannot be changed since the patent has already been granted.