# patent images and pdf file can not be seen or downloaded, how come?

Tags: us9010037

In reference to the patent: [US9010037](https://www.google.com/patents/US9010037)

patent images and pdf file can not be seen or downloaded, how come?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that presently Google Patent displays error while viewing or downloading pdf copy of the said patent but, please note they are just information provider you can download the pdf and scan images from other resources like USPTO or Espacenet.

for more information on [How do you correct errors in Google Patents?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/12392/11895)

For queried patent you can download pdf copy via visiting expacenet or USPTO image database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix:

BACKGROUND:
Google fairly recently rolled its patent search into the general search. It seems that since then the images and download PDF have been unreliable.

FIX:
Go to the OLD google patent URL (https://patents.google.com/) type in the patent number there, you will find that the images and download PDF features still work on the old google patents URL. This will give you a proper PDF with actual text (not just images), searchable, and all the other PDF features like highlighting and commenting.

(at least, as at August 30th 2016)

Answer (score 0):

Another excellent site for searching for patents is [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/). I've had success obtaining patent images and downloads there when they don't show up in patents.google.com. The Lens is my preferred site for patent search at this point.