# Download pdf on new google patent

Tags: google-patents

I'm not able to download patents directly from google page on the new version of google patent (I might be tired and not finding button) https://patents.google.com/patent/EP0496181A1/en

while it is possible with old version : https://www.google.com/patents/EP0496181A1?cl=en

Any possible explantion?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I believe there are other questions that cover this issue.

Comment: http://patents.stackexchange.com/a/16369/18033 this has been identified on this site before. We are not affiliated with google, so unfortunately there is nothing we can do. There are however plenty of workaround (old g patent, other patent sites). I vote to close as off topic because of this. Sorry