# What does the title "Assigm" mean? Is it a typo?

Tags: history, specific-patent, title

In reference to the patent: [US383746](https://www.google.com/patents/US383746)

In the drawing and description it refers to the item as a "Lubricator", but the title of the patent is shown as "Assigm".

Comment: yes its a typo:- duplicate of  [How do you correct errors in Google Patents?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/12392/11895)